# flask-cors Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: python, django

Trying to execute simple json request on local server combined with Python and django.

my apiview.py

```
from rest_framework import generics
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from .jsonserializer import GroupSerializer, SubgroupSerializer, ProductsSerializer
from .models import pGroups, pSubgroups, Products
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route("/Group/")
# @cross_origin()

# Create your views here.

class GroupList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = pGroups.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer
```

Jquery script

```
let dropdown = $('#locality-dropdown');

dropdown.empty();

dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose product group</option>');
dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/Group/';

// Populate dropdown with list of provinces
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
  $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
    console.log(entry.name);
    dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.abbreviation).text(entry.name));
  })
});
```

And after all i log in console smthng like :

> Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8000/Group/: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

What i'm trying is : [Flask cors](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
 but seems im missing something in apiview.py .

P.S I'm complete beginner in web.
Edit: With postman i get the response

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "group_chiper": "01",
        "group_shortcut": "DRN",
        "group_name": "Drink",
        "operator": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "group_chiper": "02",
        "group_shortcut": "ML",
        "group_name": "Meals",
        "operator": 1
    }
]
```

Comment: I'm confused - are you using Flask, or Django? You appear to have both here, which just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Robin . That seems like a problem. I did everything in django and got the error when making api call

Comment: So did you add Flask just to use Flask_Cors? That isn't going to work. I'm not really too familiar with CORS and the headers required, but there are certainly packages which allow you to do that stuff with Django. Eg googling has given me this: https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/

Comment: @RobinZigmond thanks to your comment i solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Robin comment :

[django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/) is one of approaches.

Using command line install it to your root project :

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

If you are using environment you may install to it root project folder and reset the environment.

Add the installed app to your

> settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
)

MIDDLEWARE = [  # Or MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES on Django < 1.10
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

> CorsMiddleware should be placed as high as possible, especially before
>   any middleware that can generate responses such as Django's
>   CommonMiddleware or Whitenoise's WhiteNoiseMiddleware. If it is not
>   before, it will not be able to add the CORS headers to these
>   responses.

The part i was missing is to add in  settings.py

line of code

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```